# How to change Edit Text line color to white

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I want to change edit text line color to White , if it is in unfocused also it will show white color .

Comment: Use selectors.. Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this.

In your `EditText` XML properties

set `android:textCursorDrawable` to `@null` like,

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```